# Why can't I connect to Pokemon GO via "Google" option?

Tags: pokemon-go

After I press the Google option, it goes to a quick load screen and then does the normal loading. After 1 or more minutes, it says "Can't connect."

I downloaded the newest update, and I saw the new title (not the one with Gyrados or whatever that water dragon was), but still.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

There's 3 options to your question (hence why it is downvoted)

A) Could be the "Data restriction" problem. If so, the thread is a duplicate and you should see : [Unable to log into Pokemon Go on mobile data but can on wifi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285525/unable-to-log-into-pokemon-go-on-mobile-data-but-can-on-wifi)

B) You got banned by niantic for rooting your phone or for cheating in X or Y manner.

C) You got a bad "update" on a site that we don't know about and can't help you. There is, and still is, a gyarados on the loading screen of Pokemon Go.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out!  Uninstall the updated version of Pokemon go.  Go on internet and look up previous versions of Pokemon go. Download older version,  2 versions before the last update.  Make sure you have only one Google account. Log in, It will say unable to load and will send you to updated version.  Click on update and you are back in