# Pokemon go logging into google

Tags: pokemon-go

Hello wondering how can I get logged into Pokemon go.  I have an android phone latest version update on Samsung galaxy 6. Been playing for a while and one day accidentally hit sign out when Pokemon froze up.  Now it will not allow me to get back in. I click on Google sign on which is the way I originally signed up then it ask for birthday then Google account and starts over again. I'm in a never ending loop. I was able to log back in on iPad with no problems same way so I know the email is correct.  Tried uninstall and reinstall same problem.  How can I get back on with android phone using Google? Have not been able to play in 7 days from android phone.

Comment: Having similar issue. Still in never ending loop. Put in birthday ,select Google, email address for gmail ,then it goes back to birthday again. Using Samsung galaxy 6 with latest updates. Accidentally signed out when Pokemon froze. Funny thing is if do the same thing on iPad it logs right in. Tried uninstall ,clearing cache and data, rebooting, loggining in and out of Google and creating new email address to get back onto phone.  Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I connect to Pokemon GO via "Google" option?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286170/why-cant-i-connect-to-pokemon-go-via-google-option)

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out!  Uninstall the updated version of Pokemon go.  Go on internet and look up previous versions of Pokemon go. Download older version,  2 versions before the last update.  Make sure you have only one Google account. Log in, It will say unable to load and will send you to updated version.  Click on update and you are back in.

Comment: You should accept your own answer since you adequately answered your own question :)